# Using puppet and ensure latest for RPM package management

Tags: puppet, yum

Using `ensure => latest`, I have systems which do not need all of the same packages.

Will `ensure => latest` install the packages or only update if they already are present? If they are not present, I do not want them installed. This is to keep existing packages up to date with latest patches. I haven't tried it for fear of installing a package on a system which doesn't need it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it will install the package if not present.

You'll only want those resources declared on systems which have the packages - break them out into classes based on system role for those that have the packages installed.

Comment: so in my nodes.pp, add an include for each host and have a module for patches? e.g modules/patches/normal.pp and modules/patches/exceptional.pp , for instance?

Comment: @staticx You should have the package resources (with the `ensure => latest` if desired) in the modules that manage the applications - so for instance, if you have an application service that uses PHP, you'd have the PHP packages' resources in the module for that application service.

Comment: In this case, it's patches not just for applications but libraries.. for instance, `glibc` or `nss`. I am not managing those, just need to ensure they have the latest security updates.

Comment: @staticx Ahh, I see.  Puppet's not very good about being a general patch management platform (at least not with `package` resources), as you'd be defining hundreds or thousands of package resources to get the equivalent of a `yum update`.  Maybe something that will manage automated updates without package resources will work? https://github.com/example42/puppet-yum

Comment: Hmm ok, maybe something like spacewalk then?

Comment: @staticx Yup, that would be a good solution.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `ensure => latest` will install it if it's not present on the system.

You shouldn't have that package resource declared on a system which doesn't need it.